# How to use external IP address with c# icmp socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, icmp

I'm doing a small project that consists on listening for a Ping and just answer back with some info.

I thought of using a Socket Raw for ICMP as listener in server-side and just send a ping from client-side, this works fine when I put the 127.0.0.1 address in the IPEndPoint, but this just let me go for local tests.

I want to ping from another computer in my ethernet connection and I must change that 127.0.0.1 address in the server-side, thought of using 192.168.0.112 as it's my local ip address, but it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Here's my code:

**server**

```
   Socket servidor = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Icmp);   

   IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 0);

   servidor.Bind(endpoint);

   servidor.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 });
```

Any help will be really appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: When you say "it doesn´t work", what is it that happens precisely? An exception? Nothing is received?... If no exception / error message, try [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see if anything is actually being sent to the wire.